# How to extract full URLs from all paragraphs in a webpage using jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

How do I extract full URL's from all paragraphs on a web page using jsoup?  I am able to extract only the relative URL's.

**Expected:**
`http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husni_al-Zaim`

**Actual:** `/Husni_al-Zaim`

**My Code:**

```
    Elements links = doc.select("p");
    Elements linkss = links.select("a");

    for (Element link : linkss) {
        if (link.text().matches("^[A-Z].+") == true) {
            list.add(new NamedLink(link.attr("href"), link.text()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.absUrl("href")` instead of `.attr("href")`. This only works when you get the document from a webpage or parse the **full** file from disk (and thus do not massage portions from HTML to text and back as in your example).

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com").get();
Elements paragraphLinks = document.select("p a");
for (Element paragraphLink : paragraphLinks) {
    String absUrl = paragraphLink.absUrl("href");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I want to take the words that begin with capital letters, including accented uppercase

Comment: That's a different question (and I don't understand it).

Comment: @BalusC you can get full URL's when parsing a page as long as you pass the base URI to the parse method.   parse(String html, String baseUri)

Comment: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-